# This is about p-adic norm. When $\left|\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1 \right|_p<1$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is about p-adic norm.

If  $x=[\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1], \ u,v \in \mathbb{Z}, \  N \in \mathbb{N}$, then which conditions on $u,v, N$ ensures that $\left|\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1  \right|_p<1$ ?

Actually my purpose is to show when $(1 +x)^r$ or $(1-x)^r, \ r \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a rational number given that $|x|_p<1 $.

If I take $ x=[\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1]$, then clearly $(1\pm x)^{r=\frac{1}{N}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ but at the same we need to make sure whether $\left|\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1  \right|_p<1$ .

Kindly help me

Comment: Why do you ask this question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3166915/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, The question has different orientation. I thought that the first one is more lengthy and elaborated. Would you help me?  When $\left|\left(\frac{u}{v} \right)^N\pm 1  \right|_p<1, \ u, v \in \mathbb{Z}, \ N \in \mathbb{N}$  is satisfied ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question posed here: We have $\vert (\frac{u}{v})^N \pm 1\vert_p < 1 \Leftrightarrow \vert u^N \pm v^N\vert_p < \vert v^N \vert_p$ which with standard arguments implies $\vert u \vert_p = \vert v \vert_p$. Assuming, as one should, $gcd(u,v) =1$, that common $p$-adic value is $= 1$, and the original pair of inequalities is equivalent to $u^N \equiv \mp v^N$ mod $p$.

This is just a question about the residues $\bar u, \bar v$ of $u,v$ in the finite field $\Bbb Z /p$ and can be reformulated as follows: Since w.l.o.g. we assume that $u,v$ are not divisible by $p$, we have $\bar u, \bar v \in (\Bbb Z/p)^\times$, so $\bar u\cdot \bar v^{-1} \in (\Bbb Z/p)^\times$, and the question is whether the $N$-th power of that element is $\mp 1$, or in yet other words:

> the original "$+$" case is true iff the order of $\bar u\cdot \bar v^{-1} \in (\Bbb Z/p)^\times$ is exactly $2N$

(unless $p=2$, in which it just needs to be a divisior of $N$), whereas

> the original "$-$" case is true iff the order of $\bar u\cdot \bar v^{-1} \in (\Bbb Z/p)^\times$ divides $N$.

So e.g. the original "$-$" case is true for *all* $u, v$ (not divisible by $p$) if $N$ happens to be a multiple of $p-1$. As another example, the original "$-$" case is true for any $N$, and the original "$+$" case at least for any odd $N$, if $u \equiv v$ resp. $u \equiv -v$ mod $p$.

To actually compute the order of elements in finite fields is not an easy problem [in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), but in some small examples can be done by hand (and in reasonably small ones with a computer). Compare e.g. [Order of elements in finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074328/96384), [Fastest Way to Find order of element in Finite Fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257055/96384), [Easy way to find the order of elements in a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1700534/96384), [Determining orders of elements in extensions of finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424786/96384), [Element of given order in a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3084188/96384).

---

Finally, let me note that I am not sure if your proposed "answer" in [the duplicate of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3166915/96384) makes sense, and if you interpret the answers and comments in [Shw that $ \ (1+X)^a \in \mathbb{Q}$ both in $\mathbb{R}$ and $ \mathbb{Q}_p$ under some condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059249/96384) correctly by asking this exact question.